# Is this a quince and safe to eat?

Tags: identification, fruits

I took a picture of a fruit and its branch today. The fruit is yellow and appears to be similar to a quince.

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to tell you with just one picture. There are many plants with similar fruits (usually "garden"/"flower" plants). If you just brought the plant: do not eat it (on first year). A good rule: try to find the person who planted it: you may discover more nice things about the variety and original usage.

Comment: Are there any thorns on any of the branches? An image of the whole  plant would be very helpful, to give an idea of height, spread and growth habit. And what part of the world are you  in? Is this the only fruit it has?

Comment: Doesn't look like a true quince, Cydonia oblonga, which are small trees. Could be a Japanese quince of some description - Chaenomeles sp. These shrubs commonly grown against walls. A picture of the whole plant would be helpful. One of it in flower would also be very useful as a number of Chaenomeles have scarlet flowers which are unlike any other similar sort of plant.